# Restricting publications from accounts-facebook

Tags: meteor

I've setup facebook login in my meteor app using the "accounts-facebook" package. The problem is it seems to publish it's own data and a lot of it I don't want to as it contains information such as the URL of the persons facebook page and their real name. Is there a way I can control what facebook details are published?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control what user data is published (http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users). Make sure that you `meteor remove autopublish`. If an accounts package puts more than you want in a user's `profile`, which is published by default, you can use `Accounts.onCreateUser` to customize what gets put in new user documents.

Comment: I'll accept this but it does seem odd that the only way to store this information so it's not available to all clients is to use Accounts.onCreate user to move the data elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have made a modified publication

e.g you added this (or a variation of it) in your code somewhere

```
Meteor.publish("userdata", function() {
    return Meteor.users.find();
});
```

By default Meteor publishes the user information without the sensitive information like the `services`, `emails` or other attribute that is not `profile`.

You can control what data the user sees by publishing (or not publishing the fields you want).

```
Meteor.publish("userdata", function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {'profile.name' : true} });
});
```

The above would publish the `name` attribute on the `profile` object. You can change this to something else. If you want to hide the entire user `profile` you can add `_id: true` so it wont publish anything at all (except the user's `_id` which is published anyway)